# Emacs key binding open environment

Tags: environments, emacs

On Emacs, I used to have "C-c C-e" as a shortcut to "open an environment with begin and end". I changed my computer and reinstalled emacs: Mac OS 10.9 and Emacs 24.3, and now in LaTeX mode, "C-c C-e" is only closing an already opened environment. (it seems that "C-c C-t" is doing roughly the same as before but not exactly)

Similarly, "C-c C-s" is not opening a new section anymore.

Finally, "C-c C-;" used to comment region, but is not working anymore.

Any idea on how I could come back to the previous behaviour?
(I don't know the name of the commands and I fail to rebind C-c C-e...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Earlier you used [AUCTeX](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/), and now you use the standard TeX modes in Emacs, so you have to install AUCTeX yourself.

AUCTeX has never been the default TeX modes in Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using stock gnu emacs? Then see pst's answer. You may want to have a look at aquamacs, an emacs version tailored for Mac OS X. If memory serves me right, it includes auctex

Comment: Yes, Aquamacs uses AUCTeX as default TeX mode.